# Sign Up form success page not redirecting

Tags: apex, visualforce, partner

I have a custom sign up form which used to work perfectly until last weekend.

Now, after it hits success, the success page is not being fired. That's the URL I get

> https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ExternalRedirect?url=http://www.company.com.br/pt/cadastro/trial?status=ok

Instead of automatically redirecting it shows the message

> You will be redirected to myurl.com
>
> Click the button below to go to that page.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is the protocol for the external redirect? It's not shown in your example at all, which I'm pretty sure is standard behavior going from secure to not secure. Your example isn't a complete URL.

Comment: What do you mean by by that? If I use https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ExternalRedirect?url=https://www.google.com it was suppose to automatically redirect to Google is it not?

Comment: Correct, but your example was URL.com of which Salesforce would not know the protocol and would need to warn the user of the redirect because it couldn't magically figure out protocol itself. If you put Google.com as your redirect URL, it would warn the user as it should because that's not a complete URL. Update your question to include at least a sample protocol in your redirect because the way you have it now, the behavior of warning the user of the redirect is actually intended.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the URL on my example with the protocol but it still do'esn't seem to work, actually with any one I have tried so far.

Comment: I'm assuming you aren't passing this as a pageReference then. How does the redirect even get executed on success? JavaScript?

Comment: On the sign up form I put the tag <input type="hidden" name="successPage" value="http://www.company.com.br/pt/cadastro/trial?status=ok">

Comment: That's kind of confusing. Can you add the code you have for your form to your original question? There are many ways to redirect a page and without seeing exactly how you are trying to do it, it's going be to be hard for anyone to help you with this. I'd also suggest adding the protocol of your site to the actual URL anyways so you can eliminate any potential issues with that going forward.

Comment: `/servlet/servlet.ExternalRedirect` was added in Winter '16 as a security measure when redirecting users outside of Salesforce. See [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoUAAU). Are you using the [Signup Request API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2013/06/using-the-new-signup-api-to-manage-your-leads-and-deployments.html) in your custom form?

Comment: @DanielBallinger yes, I'm using the Signup Request API, which should perform everything automatically, no?